# rpmbuild exiting with error: File not found

Tags: makefile, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to build my first RPM package and struggling with the rpmbuild process.

This is my environment I have to deal with:

```
cat /home/rpmadm/.rpmmacros

%_topdir /export/standardbuild
%_tmppath /export/standardbuild/tmp
%_sourcedir /export/standardbuild/SOURCES
%_rpmdir /export/standardbuild/RPMS
%_srcrpmdir /export/standardbuild/SRPMS
%_builddir /export/standardbuild/COMP_BUILDS/%{name}
```

My Makefile looks like this:

```
packagename = metricconf

%_sourcedir = /export/standardbuild/SOURCES


# version number of package: make sure you also update the version
# number in the spec file
version = 1.0

all:
        @echo "usage: make dist | package"

install:
        if [ ! -d $(DESTDIR)/tmp/$(packagename) ]; \
        then \
                mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)/tmp/$(packagename); \
        fi
        
        cp mb_system_betrieb.yml        $(DESTDIR)/tmp/$(packagename)/mb_system_betrieb.yml
        cp metricbeat                   $(DESTDIR)/tmp/$(packagename)/metricbeat
        cp metricbeat.yml               $(DESTDIR)/tmp/$(packagename)/metricbeat.yml

dist:
        tar cvf $(packagename)-$(version).tar ../$(packagename)-$(version)
        gzip $(packagename)-$(version).tar
        cp $(packagename)-$(version).tar.gz $(%_sourcedir) && rm $(packagename)-$(version).tar.gz

package:        rpm

rpm:
        rpmbuild -ba $(packagename).spec
        rm -rf $(packagename)-$(version).tar
```

And this is my .spec file:

```
Summary:        configures Metricbeat for AIX
Name:           metricconf
Version:        1.0
Release:        0
Vendor:         Comp 
Source:         metricconf-1.0.tar.gz
BuildRoot:      %{_builddir}/%{name}-{version}

Requires: metricbeat

%description
metricconf prepares AIX for metricbeat
%prep
%setup -c
%build
%install
%files
%defattr(644,root,system)
/tmp/metricbeat.yml
/tmp/mb_system_betrieb.yml
/tmp/metricbeat
```

`make dist` works well and the .tar.gz file will be created correctly.
But the `make rpm` command fails every time with following error:

```
make rpm
        rpmbuild -ba metricconf.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /export/standardbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.cIlqQa
+ umask 022
+ cd /export/standardbuild/COMP_BUILDS/metricconf
+ cd /export/standardbuild/COMP_BUILDS/metricconf
+ rm -rf metricconf-1.0
+ /usr/bin/mkdir -p metricconf-1.0
+ cd metricconf-1.0
+ /bin/gzip -dc /export/standardbuild/SOURCES/metricconf-1.0.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xvvof -
x ../COOPmetricbeat-1.0
x ../COOPmetricbeat-1.0/metricconf.spec, 2289 bytes, 5 tape blocks
x ../COOPmetricbeat-1.0/ChangeLog, 135 bytes, 1 tape blocks
x ../COOPmetricbeat-1.0/Makefile, 885 bytes, 2 tape blocks
x ../COOPmetricbeat-1.0/README, 74 bytes, 1 tape blocks
x ../COOPmetricbeat-1.0/mb_system_betrieb.yml, 1161 bytes, 3 tape blocks
x ../COOPmetricbeat-1.0/metricbeat, 1552 bytes, 4 tape blocks
x ../COOPmetricbeat-1.0/metricbeat.yml, 1240 bytes, 3 tape blocks
+ STATUS=0
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /export/standardbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.dalqQb
+ umask 022
+ cd /export/standardbuild/COMP_BUILDS/metricconf
+ cd COOPmetricbeat-1.0
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /export/standardbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.delqQc
+ umask 022
+ cd /export/standardbuild/COMP_BUILDS/metricconf
+ cd metricconf-1.0
+ exit 0
Processing files: metricconf-1.0-0.ppc
error: File not found: /export/standardbuild/tmp/metricconf-1.0-0.ppc/tmp/metricbeat.yml
error: File not found: /export/standardbuild/tmp/metricconf-1.0-0.ppc/tmp/mb_system_betrieb.yml
error: File not found: /export/standardbuild/tmp/metricconf-1.0-0.ppc/tmp/metricbeat


RPM build errors:
    File not found: /export/standardbuild/tmp/metricconf-1.0-0.ppc/tmp/metricbeat.yml
    File not found: /export/standardbuild/tmp/metricconf-1.0-0.ppc/tmp/mb_system_betrieb.yml
    File not found: /export/standardbuild/tmp/metricconf-1.0-0.ppc/tmp/metricbeat
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.## Heading ##
```

Please, can anyone explain to me why rpmbuild is looking in "/export/standardbuild/tmp/metricconf-1.0-0.ppc" for the files and not in "/export/standardbuild/COMP_BUILDS/metricconf/metricconf-1.0" ???

I read a lot about building rpms especially at Fedora's doc pages, but it doesn't matter what I change in the Makefile or .spec file, the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

Your `%build` and `%install` phases are both empty, so it's not doing anything. All you have is `%prep` which is untarring it into a temporary staging area.

Look around for examples, *e.g.* if you are using `autoconf` you probably want `%configure`.

ETA: It also looks like you are trying to put your final files into `/tmp` on the target machine, which won't work because they will disappear after a reboot. `%files` should list the files to be installed on the target *without* any leading temporary paths.

Comment: Hi Aaron,
Thanks for your answer. Files moved to /tmp to process it further in the %post script. Thats correct so far. 
I still don't understand where the variable for the folder is set to "/export/standardbuild/tmp/metricconf-1.0-0.ppc/tmp/"
I will check out for the %configure macro.

Comment: Don't do that. The RPM lists where the files go. Otherwise you will cause problems for things like automated scanners that will run `rpm -aV` on your machine and list tons of missing files. Put them in a known absolute location. If you need to drop a symlink or two in `%post`, that's OK.